# Applying org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm within custom Gradle plugin not working

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a custom Gradle plugin using Kotlin. The goal is to *apply* and *configure* certain plugins within this custom plugin. Consumers should only need to apply the custom plugin and be all set.

**The problem:**
I want to apply these two kotlin plugins (and other plugins) in the custom plugin (which can be applied like this normally in a Gradle build script):

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.10"
```

But when applying them from within my own plugin a couple of things goes wrong.

1. The `jar` task is not found. I get this complaint in the project consuming my plugin.
2. The contents of the `dependencies` section, e.g `api`, `implementation` etc are also causing errors, like if Gradle doesn't understand what they are.

I can, in the consuming project however, simply add the line below to the build script to get the `jar` task back, and make `dependencies` work again:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
```

I also wrote a sort of debug function in the consuming Gradle build, just to see what plugins are applied. They all print `true` when I apply *only* my own plugin (or add kotlin-jvm to the script manually). Which seems to me like my own plugin is doing its job.

```
open class GreetingTask : DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun greet() {
        println("hello from GreetingTask")
        println(project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("org.springframework.boot"))
        println(project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("io.spring.dependency-management"))
        println(project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("com.github.ben-manes.versions"))
        println(project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"))
        println(project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring"))
        println(project.pluginManager.hasPlugin("java"))
    }
}
```

My apply method so far in my plugin:

```
override fun apply(project: Project) {
    configureRepositories(project)
    configureTesting(project)
    configureJava(project)
    configureSpringBoot(project)
    configureSpringDependencyManagement(project)
    configureKotlin(project)
    configureVersions(project)
    configurePublishing(project)
}
```

And for setting up Kotlin:

```
private fun configureKotlin(project: Project) {
    project.pluginManager.apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    project.pluginManager.apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")

    project.tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach { task ->
        task.kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        task.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

All  the other `configureXYZ` seems to work out fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was *how* I applied the plugin.

**This does *NOT* work:**

build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.praqma:demo:1.0.0")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "com.praqma.demo.DemoPlugin")
```

**This *does* work:**

settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("gradle.demoPlugin") version "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```